# Why header fixed but other cells intersects header css or vb.net?

Tags: css, asp.net, vb.net

I have a header create in asp but and i have a fixed css like that for header:

```
.fixed 
{
    position: fixed;
}
```

When start my app header intersect all cells like in picture:
[image]

What i wrong?

Comment: Without the markup we can't help you out.

Comment: Look at my edit image

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty unclear from your question/provided information as to what you are asking. Based on what I inferred, the problem is *Why is the fixed header mixing up with the other elements on the screen?*.

### Reason

When you set `position: fixed` that particular element is taken out of the normal document flow and the DOM behaves as if the element doesn't even exist. In that scenario, the elements below the fixed element would go up to occupy the now available space.

### Fix

To fix this, add some `padding-top` to `body`. The value should be more than the height of your fixed element.

```
body {
    padding-top: 100px; /* Assumed */
}
```

Also, if you want, add some background color or shadow to the fixed element for better clarity but that's your personal choice.

Comment: Header going down with all rows 100 px

Comment: Again, without the markup, I can't help much. You probably need to set `top: 0;` for `.fixed` class too.